# redefining row numbers (index)

Tags: indexing, row, redefinition, redefine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the index number of a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567790/change-the-index-number-of-a-dataframe)

I did various operations with a dataframe and excluded a number of rows.
As you see in my example the dataframe now starts with 366.
I would like to redefine this row number back to 1 and of course the following index numbers.

```
 -> head(new_pred)
pred_mean_temp pred_precipitation pred_visibility pred_wind
366     -0.4707149          156.00677       260.24943 12.006212
367      3.3950894           85.07009        28.66573 12.618096
368      0.9394914          276.67157        12.39165  8.249188
369     -2.9786171          147.03749        10.21351  7.432625
370     -3.5502385           24.66432        16.59086 13.495728
371     -4.2262573           37.21946        17.51434  9.309708
```

so it will look like this:

```
-> head(new_pred)
pred_mean_temp pred_precipitation pred_visibility pred_wind
1     -0.4707149          156.00677       260.24943 12.006212
2      3.3950894           85.07009        28.66573 12.618096
etc.
```

best thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple:

```
 dimnames(new_pred)[[1]]<-seq_len(nrow(new_pred))
```

Answer (score 0):

`rownames(new_pred) <- seq(nrow(new_pred))` is simpler, and `rownames(x) <- NULL` is simpler still.