# How can i change the numbering of the index in a pivot table (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have gathered my data into a pivot table of the following form :

```
movie_id  1     2     3     4     5     ...  
user_id                                 ...                              
1          1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0  ...   
2          1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   
3          NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   
4          NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...
5          1.0   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...  
6          1.0   NaN   ....
.          .....
.
.
943
```

What i need is my (user_id) index to change its numbering from 1-943 to 943-1886 so that i can run some algortihms later, in which the movie ids will be different than the user ids. Is that possible in some way?

edited console:

```
movie_id  1     2     3     4     5     ...   943 
944       1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   
945       1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   
946       0.0   0.0   0.0 
.
.
.
```

Comment: `df.index = df.index + 942`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 10), (2, 11), (3, 12), (4, 13), (5, 14)], columns=['movie_id', 'user_id'])
>>> df
   movie_id  user_id
0         1       10
1         2       11
2         3       12
3         4       13
4         5       14
>>> df.index = range(943, 948)
>>> df
     movie_id  user_id
943         1       10
944         2       11
945         3       12
946         4       13
947         5       14
```

If you want to rename your index column, just do this

```
>>> df.index.names = ['my_index']
>>> df
          movie_id  user_id
my_index                   
943              1       10
944              2       11
945              3       12
946              4       13
947              5       14
```

Alternative, you can do this

```
>>> df.index = pd.RangeIndex(start=943, stop=948, step=1, name='my_index')
>>> df
          movie_id  user_id
my_index                   
943              1       10
944              2       11
945              3       12
946              4       13
947              5       14
```

Comment: Or maybe [Change the index number of a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7567790/8791891) would be useful.

Comment: my_pivot_table.index = range(943,1886) actually worked. Thank you for your help!

Comment: actually whould you maybe happen to  know why my console isn't showing my indexe's name (user_id) anymore; It just shows the columns' name now (movie_id)...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Please clarify your explanation.

Comment: I haven't lost any data.  It's just that when i show the rearranged pivot table,  my index name isn't showing in the console.  It just shows the columns' name. The name of the index which is user_id isn't showing anymore.  I hope i've explained it a bit better... thanks again for showing interest btw

Comment: Or try to `df.index.names = ['my index']` to give the index name to `my index`

Comment: You can also rename any column by `df.rename(columns={'old_name': 'new_name'})`.

Comment: i edited my question post to show the console output now. check it out if possible. i also tried to rename my index but it didnt chnange anything...

Comment: Sorry, I can't help much. I cannot reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

my_pivot_table.index = range(943,1886) worked in changing the numbering of the pivot table's index!